# No /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, usb, ip

I followed https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/USB%20Gadget%20Configfs%20API_0.pdf and complied the kernel with

```
Device drivers
  [*] USB support
    <M> USB Gadget Support
      <M> USB Gadget functions configurable through configfs 
        [*] Function filesystem (FunctionFS)
```

I installed the modules and placed the kernel in `/boot` of my Raspberry Pi 3B and rebooted.

I don't see `/sys/kernel/config/usb-gadget` folder. when i try to create it with `sudo`, it says, **operation not permitted**.

Because of the above error I fail to run https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/tools/usb/usbip/vudc/vudc_server_example.sh

Comment: First make sure that the corresponding modules are getting loaded (use `lsmod`) and if not, use `modprobe` to load them. Also make sure that you build the appropriate controller and gadget driver modules.

Comment: @TooTea what do you mean by corresponding module?

Comment: `find /lib/modules -name gadget` lists `/lib/modules/4.19.89-v8+/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget` but `modprobe gadget` or `modprobe usb-gadget` says module not found. what module should i've to probe?

Comment: I'm trying to connect my android phone to the raspberrypi as a gadget

Comment: Ok, `modprobe g_mass_storage` created `/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget`